# How can I include the value of a variable inside a string? - C#

Tags: c#

I have text that I need to display to a user, but some of it is based off of a variable which will keep changing, like so:

```
string s = "The current time is <currentTime>.";
```

'currentTime' is the variable I need to display. How can I add the value of the variable into the string?

Comment: I don't know how I didn't find that question when I was looking if someone had done this already. You can go ahead and close this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C# 6.0, you can insert variables into a string by creating an [Interpolated String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). Otherwise your options are concatenation or the [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Any of these methods will produce the desired result:

```
The current time is 10:24:43.47344233.
```

### Interpolation

```
string s = $"The current time is {currentTime}.";
```

By adding a `$` before the first quote, C# will recognize it as an interpolated string, look for variable names inside curly braces, and replace them with their values.

### Concatenation

```
string s = "The current time is " + currentTime + ".";
```

This basically attaches strings to either side of a variable value. It's pretty straightforward, but it means you need to pay attention to your spacing and formatting.

### String.Format

```
string s = String.Format("The current time is {0}.", currentTime);
```

This is slightly more complex. The Format method takes a string and any number of expressions as arguments, and inserts the values of the expressions into the string where indicated by the numbered brackets. So {0} will be replaced with the first expression, {1} will be replaced with the second, and so on.

If you want to format the variable values, you can also apply standard [numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) or [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) format strings when using either interpolated strings or the String.Format method.

Comment: Options are `$`, `string.Format` and `string + object + string`.